# C# best way to update entire sql table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I am trying to make a program better. What it does is take a C# datatable and insert it to a sql table as a bulk copy. What I am trying to achieve is to have the whole table rewritten with the new values, but what happens is, if for some reason I got an error on the copy, the table will be empty at the end.

How can I avoid the table to be deleted when the bulk copy fails?

This is my current code.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
    bc.DestinationTableName = "vehicle";
    bc.BatchSize = vehicleData.Rows.Count;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.vehicle");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    bc.WriteToServer(vehicleData);
    bc.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You got an error. Can we hope that you share the error message with us?

Comment: I don't have the error since it hasn't happen while in debugging so im not sure, i don't have access to the computer where it is actually running.

Comment: @Eser don't worry, the question's purpose was not that error, but there is a solution to it, but thanks for trying to use your divine powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute everything inside a transaction:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.vehicle"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        using (var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = "vehicle";
            bc.BatchSize = vehicleData.Rows.Count;
            bc.WriteToServer(vehicleData);
        }
        ts.Complete(); // Commit
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

If something fails within the transaction, everything will be rolled back.

See: [TransactionScope Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @oliver thanks, that's exactly what i needed, i didn't know transactions could be used inside c#